# Redirect old URL with params to new URL with totally new params in web.config

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

I've been looking around for over two days now but I can't get this simple task to work in web.config:

Redirect a full URL with params to a full NEW URL with other params.

I.e.: 
Redirect this:
h--p://www.somedomain.net/index.php?some=examples&someother=examples
to this
h--p://www.someotherdomain.net/blabla.php?all=kind&off=new&variables=ok

---

This is the closest I could get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rule01" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="http://www.somedomain.net/index.php?sid=73742&amp;lang=nl" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.someotherdomain.net/survey/index.php?r=survey/index&amp;sid=73742&amp;lang=nl" appendQueryString="false" />
                    <serverVariables>
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But that redirects me from:
h--p://www.somedomain.net/index.php?sid=73742&lang=nl
to:
h--p://www.someotherdomain.net/survey/?sid=73742&lang=nl
where it should be:
h--p://www.someotherdomain.net/survey/index.php?r=survey/index&sid=73742&lang=nl

I hope the above is clear and someone can help me out, it's driving me nuts that i can't figure this out! :S